# What does [雲行]{くもゆ}き mean?

Tags: meaning

What does [雲行]{くもゆ}き mean? I looked this up on Google Translate, and it means "turn of affairs" which makes no sense to me. I looked this up on Google Images, and there are pictures of storm clouds.

My guess is that 雲行{くもゆ}き means storm clouds, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

雲行き means:
① the direction of the clouds' move, and
② the prospect of the development of an event.

"雲行き" is most often used in the way as 雲行きが[怪]{あや}しい (or [険]{けわ}しい), meaning the thing (situation) looks (somewhat) precarious, for example:

> 彼と奥さんと、どうやら雲行きが怪しいようだ。
>   The relationship between them (he and his wife) doesn’t seem to be going well.
>   TPP交渉の雲行きが険しい。
>   The prospect of concluding the TPP Agreement is thinning away.

Comment: Trans-Pacific Partnership

Comment: 四字熟語の「[行雲流水]{こう・うん・りゅう・すい}」と関係ある？

Comment: @nodakai. Yes. It was a typo of TPP. I corrected  spelling. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @istrasci. According to 大辞林, “行雲流水” means to behave naturally like a carefree cloud flying  in the sky and water running freely in the stream without sticking to anything. “行雲” means “a passing cloud (in the sky)” with an emphasis on the cloud. So I think it’s a bit different from “雲行き” which means the direction or movement of a cloud with emphasis on the direction.

Comment: @Chocolate. Thanks for your editing to make the lines more readable and corrections of my "habbitual" typos. But please hold back from making unnecessary changes. For an example,  "move" of a cloud can  stay as it is. I understand you know well that  'move' can e used as a noun. To me the word, "movement"  sounds too heavy to describe 雲行き.

Comment: 申し訳ありません…そこは戻しました。他にお気に召さないところなどがありましたら編集なさってください。逆にお手数をおかけするようですみませんが。

Answer (score 4):

As I could find out, 雲行き has two meanings:

> 1. Cloud drift, cloud movement

It can be clear from the very kanjis. Not necessarily storm clouds, but it's also possible.

And Google translate was right:

> 2. Turn of affairs / current situation

Again, judging by kanjis, it seems to me that in this case "how things are going" has the close meaning.

Answer (score 1):

雲行き literally means the way clouds [行]{ゆ}く

道行き is an archaic word for itinerary.

東京行き means bound for Tokyo. Similarly, 地獄行き is bound for Hell. Their [行]{ゆ}き parts are often pronounced as [行]{い}き in modern Japanese.

Hope you get some ideas on how 行き, a noun form of a verb [行]{ゆ}く "go," can be used in Japanese.